# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement on different weblogic server

Tags: java, hibernate, weblogic12c

I have a simple create query in my application.( Spring 5.2.10 + Hibernate 5.4.3.1 + Weblogic 12c)

It works good on my local weblogic server but it takes error on another weblogic server when flush. They uses same datasource.

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statementjavax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1366)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1349)
    at com.thy.dao.impl.BaseDAOImpl.create(BaseDAOImpl.java:46)
```

I tried to configure weblogic.xml prefer application packages like below , still not works.

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

Comment: How can we help you when you don't show use the SQL query that fails? Plus are you using the same database in both cases?

Comment: I can't share queries because for company restriction, it is simply session.persist(entity);
session.flush();

Comment: I assume that you don't use the same database schema

Comment: in the stacktrace of the SQLGrammarException there should be the why. if you can't share the query and the exception could you alter names maintaining consistency and tell us a similar query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, there is no error in sql grammar. Problem releates with a stored procedure/function in db side which triggerred with a new insert. Stack trace not contains this exception , I found it in weblogic logs.